# Use of static variable associated with activity in async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity A with static variable s. I pass the activity instance to async task for some processing. Suppose, in the mean time activity is closed (garbage collected) by  android OS and `AsyncTask` is running in background.
 In `AsyncTask` now it is trying to access A.s which is not available so, it throws an exception. Is there any Solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: thats why parameters are there, pass values you want as parameters to asynctask

Comment: i dont see any need for a static variable.All i see is memory leaks in your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Stop the asyncTask when the activity is closed. So the asyncTask will not try to access the activity anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just add null checks to avoid the exception. **Example:**

```
if (A != null && A.s != null) {
   // proceed with your attempt to update the A.s variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, don't keep s as static just pass it to the doInBackground method and collect back the result from onPostExecute method .

```
private class someLongRunningOperation extends AsyncTask<ArrayList, Progress, Result>{

        @Override
        protected Result doInBackground(ArrayList... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           String s=params[0];
           //Do operations on the data   
            ...
            return s;
        }   
}
```

Call:

```
someLongRunningOperation longTask= new someLongRunningOperation ();
longTask.execute(yourList1, yourList2, yourList3...);
```

Note that the problem that you described can also happen during the screen orientation changes, If you are using a fragment use

```
 setRetainInstance(true);
```

to save your data across activity recreations.